# Generating table

Tags: vbscript, hta

I am trying to push my output from VBScript code in table row and table cell.

My code is:

```
Set table = document.CreateElement("table") 
i = 0
For Each node In objMSXML.selectNodes(sXPath)
    Set tr = document.createElement("tr")
    Set td = document.createElement("td")
    For Each element In node
        td.innerText = element.parentNode.nodeName & "->" & element.text
        tr.appendChild td
    Next
    table.appendChild tr
    ObjOutFile.WriteLine node.parentNode.nodeName & "->" & node.text
    i = i + 1
Next
document.body.appendChild table
```

What is wrong with it? it is not working while I am able to push output in list.

**Edit**
I am using this code it prints output as expected but table is not populated.

```
ObjOutFile.WriteLine thing.path
document.body.appendChild p
Set tbody = document.createElement("tbody") 
For Each node In objMSXML.selectNodes(sXPath)
    Set trow = document.createElement("tr")
    Set tcol = document.createElement("td")
    tcol.innerText = tcol.innerText & node.parentNode.nodeName & "->" & node.text
    ObjOutFile.WriteLine node.parentNode.nodeName & "->" & node.text
    trow.appendChild(tcol)
    tbody.appendChild(trow)
    'ObjOutFile.WriteLine node.parentNode.nodeName & "->" & node.text
Next
document.appendChild(tbody)
```

The `ObjOutFile.writeLine` prints like:

```
C:\Users\abc\Desktop\samp.txt
hamster->AbcPos
hamster->Database Layer
hairyStyle->qskxyz
hairyGirl->qixyz
hairyGirl->abc
hairyGirl->def
```

Comment: "Is not working" is an insufficient problem description. What *exactly* does not work as expected?

Comment: It doesn't populate any table on page, or maybe table in empty so invisible. but my variables has data. So table should come

Comment: Which page? Does this code run in an HTA? A Classic ASP page?

Comment: In HTA, this runs in an hta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues in your code:

- `node` is not a collection, so `For Each element In node` fails. You probably have an `On Error Resume Next` elswhere in your HTA that is hiding this error, because otherwise you'd be seeing an error message like this:

  > Object doesn't support this property or method.
- You need to append the table rows to a `<tbody>` element first (see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28460754/1630171)).

Change your code to something like this (and remove the `On Error Resume Next`):

```
Set table = document.createElement("table")
Set tbody = document.createElement("tbody")
i = 0
For Each node In objMSXML.selectNodes(sXPath)
    Set tr = document.createElement("tr")
    Set td = document.createElement("td")
    td.innerText = node.parentNode.nodeName & "->" & node.text
    tr.appendChild td
    tbody.appendChild tr
    i = i + 1
Next
table.appendChild tbody
document.body.appendChild table
```

Comment: Thanks the link was helpful. to understand problem.

Answer (score 0):

You want a row for each node and a column for each element of the current node. So

```
For Each node In objMSXML.selectNodes(sXPath)
    Set tr = document.createElement("tr")
    Set td = document.createElement("td")
    For Each element In node
        td.innerText = element.parentNode.nodeName & "->" & element.text
        ...
```

should be

```
For Each node In objMSXML.selectNodes(sXPath)
    Set tr = document.createElement("tr")
    For Each element In node
        Set td = document.createElement("td")
        td.innerText = element.parentNode.nodeName & "->" & element.text
        ...
```